# How to show last record for one column which have duplicate value or not with count of how many times value of column is shown

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
id       iduser
1        14463
2        14463
3        14463
4        14463
14       14464
15       14465
5        14790
6        14790
7        14790
8        14790
9        14790
13       14790
16       14790
17       14790
18       14790
21       15135
22       15265
19       16287
20       16287
```

I want out put

```
id       iduser count
4        14463 4
14       14464 1
15       14465 1
18       14790 9
20       16287 2
21       15135 1
22       15265 1
```

I’ve used query

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM   tb_facultyCall c 
WHERE  c.id IN (SELECT Max(id) id 
                FROM   tb_facultyCall 
                GROUP  BY id_user)
```

By this  I get output

```
id       iduser
4        14463
14       14464
15       14465
18       14790
20       16287
21       15135
22       15265
```

Now I only require count `iduser` columns

Comment: ok, then u tell me how to show any table by code format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, just use `COUNt` and `MAX` in the same query:

```
SELECT 
  id_user, 
  MAX(id) id, 
  COUNT(id) AS Count
FROM tb_facultyCall
GROUP BY id_user;
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to select more columns other than `id_user`, then you can join this as a subquery and select the other columns you want to select:

```
SELECT
  c.*, -- you can select here the more columns you want
  t.count
FROM tb_facultyCall AS c
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
      id_user, 
      MAX(id) Maxid, 
      COUNT(id) AS Count
    FROM tb_facultyCall
    GROUP BY id_user
) AS t ON c.id_user = t.id_user AND t.Maxid = c.id
```

Comment: further i require to use inner join in my query, where ur code will gives error. bcz there is one column in group by clouse, and i need to show many others column

Comment: @SheenuMehra - For the many others columns that you have to display, do you want to group by them or use aggregate function with them. Can you please add some more sample data for those columns to edit the query accordingly?

Comment: for other columns i need not to use any aggregate function

actually my table has also some more columns, on which i cant use any function

My actual query is like

select c.*, u.Urnno as urn, u.UserName as UserName from tb_facultyCall c
inner join tbUser u on u.UserId=c.id_user
where
c.id in (SELECT   
        t1.[id]
FROM [tb_facultyCall] t1
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT id_user,
                       MAX(id) id
                FROM tb_facultyCall
                GROUP BY id_user
             ) sub
    ON sub.id = T1.id)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Hope it helps you.

Updated Answer:

```
SELECT A.*, B.cnt 
FROM tb_facultyCall A
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT id_user,Count(id_user) AS cnt 
FROM tb_facultyCall
GROUP BY id_user) B
WHERE A.id_user= B.id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep grouping by id_user and add count to your query:

```
select MAX(id) id, id_user, COUNT(id) total from tb_facultyCall
group by id_user
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
Result using DENSE_RANK() :

SELECT MAX(ID)   AS ID,
       IDUSER,
       COUNT(RN) [COUNT],
FROM   (SELECT DENSE_RANK()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY IDUSER )RN,
               *
        FROM  YOURTABLE)A
GROUP  BY IDUSER
```